# Как не считать пробелы и другие символы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сосчитать только буквы отбросив пробелы и всякие другие символы? Наверно это уже делается с помощью `jQuery`?

```
<textarea onkeyup="document.getElementById('meta_d_count').innerHTML=this.value.length" name="text" class="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="meta_d_count"></div>
```

Comment: _всякие другие символы_ - это какие?

Comment: @Grundy, все кроме букв, `-,./+`

Comment: цифры считаются? буквы английские или любые?

Comment: да, цифры считаются, буквы любые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) и заменить ненужные символы на пустую строку, и затем посмотреть длину

```html
<textarea onkeyup="document.getElementById('meta_d_count').innerHTML=this.value.replace(/[^\wа-яё,./+-]/gi,'').length" name="text" class="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="meta_d_count"></div>
```

Comment: русские буквы не считаются

Comment: @emtecif, обновил регулярное выражение для замены